# DiscordJS filtering users from buttons and limiting buttons to user who used command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a bot that lets users create embeds using a series of commands and its going well. But I encountered a problem, the bot uses buttons but to confirm something like "Are you sure this is your title?" any user can click the button; which is a problem. I only want the user who used the command to be able to use the buttons.

Here is what I tried at the start:

```
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
const filter = m => !m.author.bot && m.author.id === interaction.user.id;
const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageCollector({filter, max:1, time:10000});

if (!interaction.isButton() && interaction.user.id != interaction.message.author.id) return;
```

I tried to use `interaction.user.id !=` or `=== interaction.message.author.id` but that doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to make a button only for a single user is to put the user ID in the custom ID

For example, set the ID to `title-${interaction.user.id}`

```js
if(!interaction.isButton()) return;
if (!interaction.customId.endsWith(interaction.user.id)) {
  return interaction.reply({
    content: "This button is not for you",
    ephemeral: true
  })
}
```

Comment: Why is there a downvote? Did I read the question wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the code correctly, but wouldn't this mean that the command only works towards 1 user? I want the buttons to automatically only work for the user who started the command, but anyone can still use the command, there is also 23 buttons in total. Also, where would your example `title-${interaction.user.id` go? in the .setCustomId of the button?

Comment: Yes, it would go in setCustomId

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution; it works. It was just a little painful to implement since there's a lot of stuff to replace but it works. Thanks!

Comment: I know this is old but thanks for the simple solution. Before this, I had to generate a string of 30 characters and assign it to each user after they ran a command. I smacked my head after I realized I could just assign the userID. Thanks again! +1

Answer (score 1):

```
client.on("interactionCreate", async (interaction) => {
  //filter the user so it only works for the user who sent the command
  if (interaction.user.id !== message.author.id) {
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setDescription("You Cannot Interact With This Message!")
      .setColor("RED");
    return interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed], ephemeral: true });
  } else {
    //Code Here
  }
});
```

idk if you still need it but

hope it works, it works for me